# Error special symbol can't convert to html

Tags: php

This is my example:

```
$str = "A Comprehensive Beginner&amp;#8217;s Guide";
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8");
```

Result: `A Comprehensive Beginner&amp;#8217;s Guide`

How to convert `&amp;#8217;s` to `'s`

Comment: Just write it in your String. Your String doesn't contain any applicable characters for `htmlentities()`.

Comment: regex can be solution of this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `htmlspecialchars_decode` to convert special HTML entities back to characters:

```
$str = "A Comprehensive Beginner&amp;#8217;s Guide";
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str);
```

**Output:**

> A Comprehensive Beginner’s Guide

**Reference:** http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php